# electron-packager: How to include specific node_modules in dist?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I'm very new to Electron and I have created [this dumb demo app](https://github.com/avmax/electron-demo).
It works fine if I run it with `electron .`, but when I build it with `electron-packager`, the dev tools tell me that it did not find several node_modules (like bootstrap, jquery), which I wanted to use.

How can I include `bootstrap`, `jquery` and `electron-notifications` (and their dependencies) in dist?

How do Electron users usually resolve this problem and how do they include specific `node_modules`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

electron-packager will work with other node modules but I found my issue to be that I had the module I was using to be in both "dependencies" and "devDependencies" You need these modules to be in "dependencies" only and not in both.  It will prune any modules listed in "devDependencies".

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way is to reinstall the modules with

```
$ nmp install <package name> --save
```

Than you have the modules saved. And you don't have to change your code.
You can also write after the --save --dev

Comment: they are already in Dependencies section, not in DevDependencies

Answer (score -3):

just use electron-builder. it works as expected right out of the box